# Blazor WASM Azure Static Web App, Functions not working

Tags: azure, azure-functions, blazor-webassembly, azure-static-web-app

I created a simple Blazor WASM webapp using C# .NET5. It connects to some Functions which in turn get some data from a SQL Server database.
I followed the tutorial of BlazorTrain: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5QctDo9MWps

Locally using Azurite to emulate the Azure stuff it all works fine.
But after deployment using GitHub Action the webapp starts but then it needs to get some data using the Functions and that fails. Running the Function in Postman results in a `503: Function host is not running.`

I'm not sure what I need to configure more. I can't find the logging from Functions. I use the injected ILog, but can find the log messages in Azure Portal.
In Azure portal I see my 3 GET functions, but no option to test or see the logging.

Comment: are you able to run the functions independently from postman or portal ?

Comment: @Aravind: Do you mean using the URL? No the same error. And I can't find how to run the functions using portal.

Comment: on the function app page click functions on the left menu and then click the appropriate function method and then click the Code+test  and then use the test and run option . make sure the function has a valid consumption or app service plan and also if it does not have any errors during startup.

Comment: I don't have a separate function app. The functions are part of the Static Web App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Aravid I found my problem.
Because I locally needed to tell my client the URL of the API I added a configuration in `Client\wwwroot\appsettings.Development.json`.
Of course this file doesn't get deployed.

After changing my code in `Program.cs` to:

```cs
  var apiAddress = builder.Configuration["ApiAddress"] ?? $"{builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress}/api/";
  builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Api",(options) => {
                options.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiAddress);
            });
```

My client works again.

I also added my SqlServer connection string in the `Application Settings` of my `Static Web App` and the functions are working as well.

I hope somebody else will benefit from this. Took me several hours to figure it out ;)